# Как изменить фон по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Как изменить фон-картинку по нажатию на кнопку? У меня получилось сделать только изменение цвета фона. Я новичок в js, да и целом в вебе.

```js
var colorArray = ["#0DC2FF", "#007DE8", "#0E5DFF", "#0C28EB", "#1600FF"];
var i = 0;

function changeColor(){
    document.body.style.background = colorArray[i];
    i++;
    if( i >= colorArray.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

```css
.page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.button {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;

    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    color: #000;
    font-weight: 900;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    padding: 1rem 3rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.button:hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.button, 
.button:active, 
.button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <title>JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="page">
  <button class="button" onclick="changeColor();">Click</button>
 </div>

 <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var colorArray = ["#0DC2FF", "#007DE8", "#0E5DFF", "#0C28EB", "#1600FF"];
var i = 0;

function changeColor(){
    //document.body.style.background = colorArray[i];
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('t.png')"; //Если файл в корне, если путь другой, укажите путь перед t.png
    i++;
    if( i >= colorArray.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не работает. Попробовала без массива, просто при нажатии один раз изменить фон, но пусто. Путь точно верный.

Comment: С наступившим Вас. Работает, проверил. Добавил ответ в соответствии с Вашей функцией.

Comment: Вас тоже) Да, работает, спасибо большое)